# Get app's URL of wansview IP camera video feed

Tags: ip-camera

I have a wansview IP camera that I just bought. And I can open VLC and input http:///mac/live/ch0?username:password and it opens a live video feed of my camera. However, if I go to my office and try that URL, then it doesn't work. I'm assuming that the ip-address is only a local IP address and I have to be connected to the same network (router) for it to work. However, wansview has this fancy app where I can view the live feed of my camera as well, and it *does* work when I am at the office. Does anyone have any idea what the url might be to this non-local feed of my camera? Or how I might be able to get it.

Comment: Have you tried sniffing the non-local network?

Comment: I haven't. Any tips on the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Try Wireshark or any other network sniffer who fits your needs. I use Kali Linux (mounted on VirtualBox) when I need to do something like that.

Comment: I very much doubt you will ever get this as a stream. The camera sends the stream to Wansview's servers and the app connects to those.